# In which direction does imidazole affect the pH?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, aromatic-compounds, heterocyclic-compounds

I'm reading something about nickel affinity chromatography and it talks about using imidazole to affect pH. In which direction does it change the pH?

Answer (score 5):

Imidazole is an amphoteric molecule and can therefore act as an acid and a base.
[image: imidazole] (courtesy of wikipedia)
It's acidity is given with $\mathrm{p}K_a=14.5$ for the proton as $\ce{N~1}$. The basic site is the lone pair at $\ce{N~3}$. Its basicity is given through the following equilibrium: $$\ce{Im + H+ <=> IMH+}$$ with a $\mathrm{p}K_a=7.05$.
[image: DOI: 10.1021/jo01066a039]([source](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/jo01066a039))
You can obtain more information about this nice little molecule on its [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imidazole#Amphoterism).

So in conclusion, it very much depends on the solution with which you are working, which effect of imidazole takes over.